# Third party QueryCryptInitServlet Configuration with SpringMVC 4.3.4 using Java Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encryption

I am configuring completely xml free configuration for Spring based application and we are using **servlet 3.0** in order use annotation support with replacement of **web.xml**

We are using `com.guhesan.querycrypt.servlet.QueryCryptInitServlet` for Query parameter Encryption. Initially we had configured using `web.xml` as of now there is no `web.xml`. So, Please suggest, how can we configure this using java configuration with **SpringMVC**

## Sample Code in web.xml (Old)

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.guhesan.querycrypt.listener.QueryCryptSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>QueryCryptServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.guhesan.querycrypt.servlet.QueryCryptInitServlet</servlet-class>       
      <init-param>
         <param-name>queryName</param-name>
         <param-value>_qx</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>debug</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Similarly how to configure with Spring using java configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can extend the Listener and Servlet, you could annotate the extended versions with the Servlet 3.0 spec annotations `@WebListener`and `@WebServlet`, these are discovered at runtime.

If you use Spring Boot you need to add `@ServletComponentScan`.

Another option is to override  `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)`, since this allows you to add additional Servlets and Listeners. Like this

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    ServletRegistration defaultServlet = servletContext.getServletRegistration("default");
    defaultServlet.addMapping("/favicon.ico");
    super.onStartup(this.servletContext);
}
```

If you do this you should be aware that startUp is called before your Spring application context is loaded, but since you probably don't need your Servlet and listener to be spring beans, that should not matter.

Comment: ServletRegistration.Dynamic addQueryCryptServlet = servletContext.addServlet("QueryCryptServlet", new QueryCryptInitServlet());
  Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
  initParams.put("queryName", "_qx");
  initParams.put("debug", "false");
  addQueryCryptServlet.setInitParameters(initParams);
  addQueryCryptServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

  // Registering QueryCryptServlet Listner
  servletContext.addListener(new QueryCryptSessionListener());